# PowerShell Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s) from within another function

Tags: powershell

I am writing my first Powershell script and coming from C# am confused, my code is below:

```
function Run(
[string] $command,
[string] $args,
[Ref] [string] $stdout,
[Ref] [string] $stderr
)
{  
    $p1 = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $p1.StartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
    $p1.StartInfo.FileName = $command
    $p1.StartInfo.Arguments = $arguments
    $p1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
    $p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false

    $p1.Start()
    $p1.WaitForExit()
}

$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
$p.StartInfo.FileName = "ping"
$p.StartInfo.Arguments = "142.553.22242.2"
$p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
$p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false

$p.Start()
$p.WaitForExit()
$code = $p.ExitCode
$stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()


Run("ping","208.67.222.222","","")
```

The $p.Start() works, but for some reason the parameters passed in to the Run function are ignored and $p1 fails. What am I doing wrong please?

```
Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified"
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\logtofile.ps1:27 char:5
+     $p1.Start()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception

Exception calling "WaitForExit" with "0" argument(s): "No process is associated with this object."
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\logtofile.ps1:28 char:5
+     $p1.WaitForExit()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

Comment: In case it helps someone:  I got similar error, and in my case, it was not permissions, it was that the EXE I was trying to start was not at that location :face_palm:  Posting in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call run as follows:

```
Run "ping","208.67.222.222","",""
```

putting in between the parentheses passes it to the function as a single array argument.

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't trying to start a process from inside a function, but I was getting the same error. It took me a few minutes to realize that it was one of my favorite time-wasters: a UAC trap. I hadn't started PowerShell using "Run as administrator". You have to have admin privileges and run the code as such to start/stop/modify processes that you don't own and this error message is totally unhelpful in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error with the start() function on a service because a colleague set the service to "disabled" in the Windows Services window. Setting it back to "Manual" fixed it.

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer the question, but this was among the first results in Google.

Answer (score -1):

```
function Demo  {
    param (
        $fileName,$Arguments
    )

    $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $p.StartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $p.StartInfo.FileName = $fileName
    $p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $p.StartInfo.Arguments = $Arguments
    $p.Start() | Out-Null
    $p.WaitForExit()

    $stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    $stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
    Write-Host "stdout: $stdout"
    Write-Host "stderr: $stderr"
    Write-Host "exit code: " + $p.ExitCode
}

Demo "getmac" " /v"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.